# Phaser: Adjust colide area to the image

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a sprite that have diferent sizes as you can see in the image, is there a Way to close the collide area to que sprite in the exact moment? Or then devide the sprite in 8 and using 2 sprites at the same time?[image]

[image]

I am deviding the sprite in 4 do animate it, but devinding in 8 only shows half of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the bounding box smaller

```
image.setSize(x, y, true);
```

[Link to Documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setSize__anchor)

And here a working example https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/smaller-bounding-box

Comment: Well, it worked better than i have expected, i though for being a sprite it would not work, but actuallly did. Thanks a lot. Game Doneeeeee